# Homebrew install specific version of hadoop 2.8.0 instead of 3.1.1

Tags: hadoop, homebrew, hadoop2

How do i install hadoop 2.8.0 instead of hadoop 3.1.1 via brew ?

alternatively, how to use brew to install downloded hadoop 2.8.0 from my desktop ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Homebrew install specific version of formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula)

Comment: HomeBrew doesn't do anything special. Do you have to use it?

Comment: Read more about it

Comment: im having same issue, any solution would be grateful